# C# Create a playlist on SoundCloud

Tags: c#, .net, api, soundcloud

I have some problems with the soundcloudapi and i hope someone can help me. All GET Methdods works perfect, but now I want to create a new playlist on SoundCloud and I alwas receive resonse 422 with message "Unprocessable Entity"

This s my current api execuion method

```
      private T Execute<T>(Uri url, HttpMethod method = null, object bodyParams = null) 
        where T: class
    {
        var uri = url.AddParameter("oauth_token", Uri.EscapeDataString(tokenKey)).AddParameter("client_id", ((SoundCloudAuthenticationOptions)AuthenticationOptions).ClientId);
        var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(method ?? HttpMethod.Get, uri);

        if (bodyParams != null)
        {
            httpRequestMessage.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bodyParams));
        }

        HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).Result;
        //  response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
        if (typeof (T) == typeof (JObject))
            return jObject as T;
        return jObject.ToObject<T>();
    }
```

And for creating a playlist I call it like

```
Execute<JObject>(apiUrl.Append("playlists"), HttpMethod.Post, new { playlist = new { title = name, sharing = "private", tracks = new string[0] } })
```

Comment: About [http error 422](http://www.restpatterns.org/HTTP_Status_Codes/422_-_Unprocessable_Entity) _For example, this error condition may occur if an XML request body contains well-formed (i.e., syntactically correct), but semantically erroneous, XML instructions_. Could it be that your `tracks` list is empty?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what the issue is, but I've used this library in the past for the SoundCloud API (the library doesnt come without its issues)

https://github.com/Haythem/SoundCloud.NET

You could take a look there, and see how they do it.

On the other hand, I was just playing around with the SoundCloud website, and tested creating a few playlists using chrome developer tools - i've found that creating a playlist with no tracks is not allowed.

You may simply want to try to execute your command with a non-empty tracks list.

Comment: Thank you very much i will check it.

Comment: Thanks i have found a different..
If i add the parameters to the url and not to the body it will work. Thanks a lot.